# Keeping ObjectId reference in an Autocad .Net WCF plugin

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, autocad, autocad-plugin

There is a .Net Autocad plugin in which a WCF service is used to call a method
on another process external to Autocad. Autocad entities are wrapped in custom classes and passed through WCF. Once the call returns the plug-in needs to write the result back into Autocad database.

Here is the problem: ObjectId is needed to fetch the object and write the result back; WCF serialize the data and ObjectId is not serializable. So I don't have access to the object.

Is there any workaround/solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the property `ObjectId.OldIdPtr` which is an `IntPtr` (serializable). To get your `ObjectId` back, just do:

```
var id = new ObjectId(oldIdPtr);
```

It's a more direct way than using the handle (which need a lookup)

Comment: Yes indeed, it's more easier. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Maxence. The ObjectId has got many other parameters(e.x Database). Would they still be valid once the ObjectId is created in this way? I shall try it.

Comment: Yes, the only state in `ObjectId` is a pointer to his unmanaged counterpart. All properties are retrieved from the unmanaged side.

Answer (score 2):

You have to serialize the value handle of the `ObjectId` since it is not serializable:

```
[Serializable]
public class TobeSerialized
{
    private long idHandleValue;
    [NonSerialized]
    private ObjectId id;

    public TobeSerialized()
    {
        this.idHandleValue = id.Handle.Value;
    }
public ObjectId GetObjectId(Database database, long handleValue)
    {
        Handle handle = new Handle(handleValue);
        ObjectId id = database.GetObjectId(false, handle, 0);
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then, when you deserialize your `Class object` you will be able to get the `objectId` by calling the method  `GetObjectId(Database database, long handleValue)`

Comment: Thanks Zimer for the answer. I am aware of this workaround. But am concerned with GetObjectId performance on large numbers. What does this method actually do? Does it create new ObjectId or look for it on the database?

Comment: @ali: Zimmer is right.  In fact, I can't see how this plugin is serializing entities otherwise.  They too contain the ObjectId.  Not to mention they are not marked serializable.  They do however implement MarshalByRefObject which means they can be sent via remoting, but not WCF (not to my knowledge anyways). My guess is they are either using some remoting magic, or they're using POCO representation of the entity properties.  If the latter is the case, then they are doing what Zimer is suggestion.

Comment: @ali: Btw... Handle's are persisted IDs with the document.  ObjectId's are transient IDs with the session.  So it's actually retrieving the session's registered ObjectId for the object from the drawing's database for the session.  The code will also has to account for the fact that the Handle is a hexadecimal value, so use this... ObjectId oid = currentDB.GetObjectId(false, new Handle(Convert.ToInt64(handle, 16)), 0);

Comment: @ali: Based on the documentation of Autodesk ObjectARX, this method returns the objectId of the object that has the handle value contained in objHandle so we can say that it will look for it on the database.

Comment: @Zimer:  Sorry about my second comment with the code example.  For some reason I thought I saw that you were using a string.  I overlooked the fact you were passing it as long.

Comment: @bjhuffine: no problem. Yes, you don't need to make the conversion because it's passed as a long type.

Comment: @bjhuffine: The plugin doesn't serialize Autocad entities but wraps them in some custom reference type that is serializable.

Comment: @ali: That's my point. Even if the entities are encapsulated in another serializable object, ALL the properties have to be serializable. You can't even use inheritance to pull that off, instead you'll end up with a SerializationException being thrown.  I think there's more to this story.  Like I said before, they're probably either using proxy objects that carry over serializable property values or are using the remoting base.  But the main point is that in order to pass an object it has to be serializable.  Since ObjectId isn't, you have to pass either its long/string value to the service.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your entity you can get handle directly without mediator (objectId).
use Entity.Handle    property. 
Further from autocad guide

Each object contained with in the Database object is assigned several unique ids. The unique ways you can access objects are:
Entity handle
ObjectId
Instance pointer
The most common method is to access an object by its Object Id. Object Ids work well if your projects utilize both COM interop and the managed .NET API. If you create custom AutoLISP functions, you may need to work with entity handles.
Handles are persistent between AutoCAD sessions, so they are the best way of accessing objects if you need to export drawing information to an external file which might later need to be used to update the drawing. The ObjectId of an object in a database exists only while the database is loaded into memory. Once the database is closed, the Object Ids assigned to an object no longer exist and maybe different the next time the database is opened.